# Installed WTP but Web -> dynamic web projects do no appear

Tags: eclipse

I installed WTP but in the web folder only appear "static web project". Why I dont have "dynamic web project". I restart, unistall, what else I can do?

Comment: Which version of Java are you using to run Eclipse?  It needs to be at least 1.6.  And *how* did you install it?

Comment: thanks for your interest in my question, I have jdk 1.7.0_09 and jre 7 installed from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7u9-downloads-1859576.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I find some kind of solution ...

Seems that there are some other components that are required, the fact is that if you install full ** Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development ** instead of only install WTP  everything works well and "Dynamic Web Project" appear.